Why is one specific picture from snipping tool becoming pixelated/compressed when pasted into WordPad?
I can paste all kind of things into a WordPad doc from snipping tool, but one picture in particular is massively compressed and looks horrible. It happens to be a picture of handwritten text. What is going on? I will paste in a normal cut/paste pair and the messed up one so you can see what I mean:
Photo1 in browser:

Photo1 pasted in WordPad:

Photo2 in browser:

Photo2 in WordPad (with part of Photo1 in same doc):


Update: I'll add that WordPad can render the image properly if I save the snip to file and import it from file into the document. Something is happening in the paste operation.

The 2nd image is reduced in colors which give these artifacts.

Yeah, but why on that specific one when the photo works?

I got the Issue , with the fix.
(1) I Copied your Image to Paste here :

No issues.
(2) Same thing I put into WordPad , where it gets noisy , looking like this :

(3) Issue is that (A) there is a lot of white background , which makes it "visually visible" that (B) During Paste , the Image has been automatically resized by WordPad.
We have to undo that automatic resizing.
(4) I did this : Select that Image in WordPad , right-click , click "resize Picture" , then make it 100% , then check the Document , which is no longer noisy :

ADDENDUM :
It will occur with all Images which get resized. It is "visually visible" when there is lot of "white" background.
Inserting [ Importing ] Image is not invoking the automatic resizing.

Issue occurs when we use "Ctrl-V" while having large image with Contrasting Colours : There is no automatic resizing when we use menu bar "Paste-Special" way.

Making it full size does fix the artifacts, but then it doesn't fit on the page.  When I grab the corner to make it fit, the artifacts come back.

Try to save the snipped picture/or the picture from the web as is - right to your filesystem, And only then upload it to the WordPad doc without copy-paste.

That's a workaround, but much less convenient than snipping and pasting.

Thats the app, It's just like you want to tell me "hey I want to customize my windows taskbar to a sprankling taskbar how can i do it? or somthing like that

Maybe you can try to use Ditto and copy paste from Ditto.
https://ditto-cp.sourceforge.io/
